# How do I specify an iOS simulator in Qt Creator?

Tags: ios, qt, ios-simulator, qt-creator

In Qt Creator, when I click the run button in the bottom left corner to build and run my program in an iOS simulator, it is using the iPhone simulator, but I want to use the iPad simulator instead.

In XCode, you can specify which iOS simulator to run via Product...Destination.  How is this done with Qt Creator?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Qt Creator, click "Projects" (on the left).  Click the "Build & Run" tab (if not already selected).  Under the tab for the simulator kit, click "Run" (assuming you already added a simulator kit). Then, under the "Run" settings, choose a "Device type" from the drop down.